# How to resample a dataframe with different functions applied to each column if we have more than 20 columns?

Tags: dataframe, resampling

I know this question has been asked before. The answer is as follows:

```
df.resample('M').agg({'col1': np.sum, 'col2': np.mean})
```

But I have 27 columns and I want to sum the first 25, and average the remaining two. Should I write this('col1' - 'col25': np.sum) for 25 columns and this('col26': np.mean, 'col27': np.mean) for two columns?

Mt dataframe contains hourly data and I want to convert it to monthly data. I want to try something like that but it is nonsense:

```
for i in col_list:
    df = df.resample('M').agg({i-2: np.sum, 'col26': np.mean, 'col27': np.mean})
```

Is there any shortcut for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, not for loop :

```py
sum_col = ['col1','col2','col3','col4', ...]
sum_df = df.resample('M')[sum_col].sum()

mean_col = ['col26','col27']
mean_df = df.resample('M')[mean_col].mean()

df = sum_col.join(mean_df)
```